# How to link CUDA dynamic libraries using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I want to know how to use CMake to dynamically link CUDA libraries, I know it seems to require some extra restrictions, but don't know exactly how to do it. Here is a simple example I wrote to illustrate my problem.

**Directory structure:**

```bash
Dir/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── header.cuh
├── kernel.cu
└── main.cpp
```

**Environment:**

- OS: Windows 11
- GPU: RTX 3060 laptop
- CUDA Toolkit: 11.6
- Platform: Visual Studio 2022

**header.cuh:**

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

extern "C" void f();
```

**kernel.cu:**

```c
#include "header.cuh"

void __global__ print()
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    printf("%d\n", idx);
}

void f()
{
    print<<<1, 10>>>();
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```c
#include "header.cuh"

extern "C" void f();

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
enable_language("CUDA")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)
set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

string(APPEND CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS " -rdc=true --cudart shared")

add_library(CUDA_COMP SHARED header.cuh kernel.cu)
set_property(TARGET CUDA_COMP PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 86-real 86-virtual)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main CUDA_COMP)
```

The project can be configured successfully, but a problem with **unresolved external symbols f referenced in function main** occurs when building it.

I also looked up the corresponding solution on Stackoverflow, but it didn't work. For example, an answer on Stackoverflow mentioned adding **" -rdc=true --cudart shared"** to cmake, and I did the same (see **line 10** of CMakeLists.txt).

This problem has been bothering me for a long time. I hope you can tell me the cause of the problem and how to solve it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you posting images of text instead of posting the text itself?

Comment: I'll refer you to [FindCUDA in CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html)

Comment: @MilanŠ. To quote your link: "Deprecated since version 3.10."... The right way today is to use CUDA as a language instead. See e.g. [Building Cross-Platform CUDA Applications with CMake](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/building-cuda-applications-cmake/). OP is doing both which might be (part of) the problem.

Comment: @paleonix didn't notice that, it's been ages since I used CUDA. Good observation though - this might be the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of issues with OP's code.

##### CUDA/C++ issues:

- CUDA nowadays is a C++ dialect, not C. Therefore I would either not declare `f()` to be `extern "C"` in the header or also do so for the definition (e.g. if a C interface is important to you).
- There seems to be no reason for the header to include anything. When something is needed by the implementation, but not by the interface, the include should not be part of the interface.
- If you want to use this header to interface with non-CUDA C++ code (a `.cpp` file) it should be named `.h` (or `.hpp`). I would expect `.cuh` files to only ever be included by `.cu` files. One also usually puts the same name on interface and implementation, so I renamed the header to `kernel.h`.
- Header guards are missing.
- Why would you redeclare `f()` in `main.cpp`? That is what the header is for.
- You forgot to synchronize after the kernel launch, so the app will most probably print nothing at all.

##### CMake issues:

- Setting properties etc. in `CMakeLists.txt` globally is discouraged. One should use the target specific APIs whenever possible. Some of these global properties have to be set before `project()` to work at all.
- CMake sets `-rdc=true` automatically when `CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION` is set.
- CUDA separable compilation is only needed when e.g. a kernel uses a device function that is defined in a different translation unit. I am not sure if OP thinks he needs it, or if the part that he needs it for was removed when creating a minimal example.
- There is the [`CUDA_RUNTIME_LIBRARY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/CMAKE_CUDA_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html) property for dynamically linking the CUDA runtime.
- Using `find_package(CUDA)` is deprecated in favor of using `CUDA` as a language or using [`FindCUDAToolkit`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html) to link against CUDA libraries like cuBLAS. OP only needs the language. But the linked documentation also lists all the CUDA libraries that come with the toolkit. Here we can see that most libraries provide a `_static` version to differentiate between static and dynamic linking. **Do not use** `target_link_libraries(... cudart)` **when using the language**, as this will not influence the `CUDA_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` property, i.e. you might get some kind of undefined CMake behavior.
- The CUDA architecture should not be hard-coded into the `CMakeLists.txt` as long as the project does not use some kind of architecture-specific intrinsics. Instead one should specify the architecture at configuration time. CMake added [`CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/variable/CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES.html) in version 3.18 so I would recommend setting the minimum to 3.18 instead of 3.17. Then you can call e.g. `cmake -DCMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=86` (not sure how this is handled in Visual Studio). I added a default for `86` that can still be overwritten at configuration time when needed.

#### Fixed Example

The following files work for me under Linux with CMake 3.23.1, CUDA 11.8.0 and GCC 11.3.0:

`kernel.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once

void f();
```

`kernel.cu`:

```cpp
#include "kernel.h"

#include <cstdio>

void __global__ print()
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    std::printf("%d\n", idx);
}

void f()
{
    print<<<1, 10>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "kernel.h"

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

# this has to be set before project()
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES)
  set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 86)
endif()

project(test LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

add_library(cuda_comp SHARED kernel.h kernel.cu)

# this command would only set the minimum standard,
# i.e. CMake can still decide to use -std=c++17 instead
# if the given compilers support C++17
target_compile_features(cuda_comp PRIVATE cuda_std_14)

set_target_properties(cuda_comp
        PROPERTIES
                CUDA_RUNTIME_LIBRARY Shared
                # CUDA_STANDARD 14 # this one cannot be changed by CMake
                # CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON # not needed for this example
)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_compile_features(main PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
# set_target_properties(main CXX_STANDARD 17)

target_link_libraries(main cuda_comp)
```