# I need a CMakeLists.txt equivalent to this Makefile line that defines an environment variable

Tags: cmake, makefile, cuda

I have a Makefile containing the following lines, which fish around for the root of the local CUDA tools folder and stuff an environment variable for later consumption. On my system it now yields '/usr/local/cuda-11.4', which is used to find headers and other things.

```
# Location of the CUDA Toolkit
CUDA_PATH = $(subst /bin/,,$(dir $(shell which nvcc)))
```

My heart's desire is to replicate this in a CMakeLists.txt file that I am presently building. I want to get the same information in a variable (or something!), and later be able to stuff it into path names, etc.

How can I do this? I have used add_definitions() in simpler ways.

Comment: While it might be possible to closely replicate the content of a Makefile in CMake, it somewhat goes against the philosophy of (modern) CMake which tries to be an abstraction over build systems like make. For example if you find yourself wanting to try out clang for compiling CUDA code, you will need to change your `Makefile` (or badly written `CMakeLists.txt`) which depends on the location of `nvcc`, while a well written `CMakeLists.txt` should work by just giving the right information to the `cmake` command at the configuration stage.

Comment: See e.g. he code at the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75174462/10107454)

Answer (score 1):

A direct translation of your code would be to use `find_program` instead of `which`,

```
find_program(NVCC_EXECUTABLE nvcc HINT ENV PATH NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

`cmake_path` with `PARENT_PATH` instead of `dir`

```
cmake_path(GET ${NVCC_EXECUTABLE} PARENT_PATH CUDA_BIN_PATH)
```

and `string` with `REPLACE` instead of `subst`.

```
string(REPLACE /bin/ "" CUDA_PATH ${CUDA_BIN_PATH})
```

However you could instead use CMake's built-in CUDA support:

```
find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)
set(CUDA_PATH ${CUDAToolkit_LIBRARY_ROOT})
```

Comment: This is legacy CMake. In most cases, one should just use `CUDA` as a language nowadays. CMake will then search for the CUDA toolkit automatically. In the few cases, where using it as language is not desirable, there is [`FindCUDAToolkit`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.htm).