# CMake and Cuda separate compilation of class constructor on device fail during linking

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, linker, nvcc

I have problem with linking constructor that is on device via CMake. It causes troubles only when calling function within class. Do you have any idea?

I tried to compile and link manually with nvcc ... -dc and -dlink and that works fine.

**Failed output**

```
ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_ZN4TestC1Ev'
CMake Error at genetic_program_lib_generated_test.cu.o.debug.cmake:282 (message):
  Error generating file
  /article/src/build/CMakeFiles/genetic_program_lib.dir/src/./genetic_program_lib_generated_test.cu.o
```

**CMake**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(GeneticProgramming)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "/article/src/build")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE debug)

include_directories(include)

# add cuda source files to variable
file(GLOB CUDA_SOURCES src/genetic_program.cu src/test.cu src/test2.cu)
file(GLOB MAIN main/main.cpp)

# find the cuda package
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

cuda_add_library(genetic_program_lib ${CUDA_SOURCES})
set_target_properties(genetic_program_lib PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

# create the executable
add_executable(out ${MAIN})
target_link_libraries(out genetic_program_lib)
```

**Main**

```
#include <genetic_program.hpp>
int main() 
{
    genetic_program();
    return 0;
}
```

**genetic_program.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
int genetic_program();
```

**genetic_program.cu**

```
#include <genetic_program.hpp>
#include <test.cuh>
int genetic_program()
{
    test<<<1,1>>>();
    return 0;
}
```

**test.cuh**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <test2.cuh>

__global__ void test();
```

**test.cu**

```
#include <test.cuh>
__global__ void test(){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    Test t;
    t.test2t();
}
```

**test2.cuh**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    public:
        __device__ Test();
        __device__ void test2t();
};
```

**test2.cu**

```
#include <test2.cuh>
__device__ Test::Test()
{
    printf("Test::Test()\n");
}
__device__ void Test::test2t()
{
    printf("Test::test2t()\n");
}
```

EDIT: Update naming convention.

Comment: `find_package(CUDA)` is legacy CMake. CUDA has lnguage support in CMake since before 3.18. See e.g. [How to link CUDA dynamic libraries using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75168735/10107454).

Comment: @paleonix Link that you provide unfortunately doesn't solve problem. I encounter it when I did my research and it's only deal with cross-compilation As I mentioned in post this problem only is with classes and classes function that are within. You are right with legacy CMake command.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. `test.cu` uses `Test` without including `test2.hpp.`

Comment: FYI: I would rename `test.hpp` and `test2.hpp` to `.cuh` because it makes clear that these should not be included in `.cpp` files, but that is a style thing.

Comment: I tried it and it is as easy as using the `CUDA` language instead of the legacy `CUDA` package. I think the legacy stuff just doesn't know the `CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION` property. I used `project(GeneticProgramming LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)`, removed `find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)` and used `add_library(genetic_program_lib ${CUDA_SOURCES})`. That is all I had to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `CUDA` language support and the `CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION` property came with CMake 3.8 and don't work together with the legacy `CUDA` package.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "/article/src/build")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE debug)

project(GeneticProgramming LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)

include_directories(include)

# add cuda source files to variable
file(GLOB CUDA_SOURCES src/genetic_program.cu src/test.cu src/test2.cu)
file(GLOB MAIN main/main.cpp)

# cuda_add_library(genetic_program_lib ${CUDA_SOURCES})
add_library(genetic_program_lib ${CUDA_SOURCES})
set_target_properties(genetic_program_lib PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON) 

# create the executable
add_executable(out ${MAIN})
target_link_libraries(out genetic_program_lib)
```

works for me.

Note that global variables like `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` need to be set before the `project` call to take effect.