# Compile CUDA and C++ in CLion with MSVC

Tags: windows, visual-c++, cmake, cuda, clion

I've just begun a small project in CUDA.

I need to know the following: Is it possible to compile CUDA library and `CPP` in the same project?
When I try `find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)`, the error says that it couldn't find 'FindCUDA.cmake'

```
src/Main.cpp: Entry point
src/module.cu: CUDA script with implementation
src/module.cuh: Declaration part of the CUDA script.
```

From `Main.cpp`, `kernel.cuh` is included. The module itself runs as an independent library, and we want to use it from Main.

My Env:

- Windows 11,
- RTX 4070 Ti,
- CUDA Toolkit 12.4
- CLion

I need to know the following: Is it possible to compile CUDA library and `CPP` in the same project?

Comment: Yes it is possible. See this link to one of my older projects https://github.com/xxxcucus/gPb

Comment: `find_package(CUDA)` is the legacy way of using CUDA in CMake. Nowadays there is a `CUDA` language in CMake.

Comment: While it is not necessarily a problem, in my experience `.cuh` is used for headers that contain e.g. device side declarations, i.e. stuff that should only be included in a `.cu` file. A C or C++ interface to a CUDA library should still use `.h` (or `.hpp` depending on preference).

Comment: See e.g my answer to [How to link CUDA dynamic libraries using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75174462/10107454) for how to use CUDA in CMake nowadays. @Cristi uses legacy CMake as well.